# If I have async middleware in ASP.NET Core 6/7 and I am getting 1000 request will there be 1000 threads (created by async) and one main thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-7.0

If I have async middleware in ASP.NET Core 6/7 and I am getting 1000 requests, will there be 1000 threads (created by async) and one main thread?

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    await _next(context);
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/ / https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: TLDR; if your tasks are waiting for I/O, then they do not consume a thread. Only when I/O completes and more code needs to run, then your task will take a thread from a thread pool. The thread pool will grow if you have too many CPU bound tasks.